# type missing when using static propTypes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't know what's happening...
when I use static propTypes in a class component．It turns out that type is missing.

```
type IProps = {
    title: string;
} & ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> 

class Test extends PureComponent<IProps> {

    static propTypes = {

    }

    render() {
        const { title } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>hello world! {title}</div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
        state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test);
```

Error message:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
  Type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.
    Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. [2345]
```

Comment: Usually there's no need to use propTypes with TS because they serve a similar purpose.

Comment: That's right, but how should I define the type correctly? Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following compiles for me.  I haven't tested that the validation does what you intend at runtime.

```
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";

// ...

static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    state: PropTypes.any
}
```

Comment: [ts]
`Argument of type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
  Type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.
    Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
      Type '{ title: Requireable<string>; state: Requireable<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. [2345]`

Comment: Oops, I failed to test with the `strict` compiler option enabled.  I updated the answer.